# React Native IOS "post install" command is throwing error

Tags: react-native, cocoapods

I am building a new React Native project on Mac. When I run "post install" command in the ios folder, I am getting the following error:

```
Installing unimodules:
 expo-application@3.2.0 from ../node_modules/expo-application/ios
 expo-constants@11.0.2 from ../node_modules/expo-constants/ios
 expo-error-recovery@2.2.0 from ../node_modules/expo-error-recovery/ios
 expo-file-system@11.1.3 from ../node_modules/expo-file-system/ios
 expo-font@9.2.1 from ../node_modules/expo-font/ios
 expo-image-loader@2.2.0 from ../node_modules/expo-image-loader/ios
 expo-keep-awake@9.2.0 from ../node_modules/expo-keep-awake/ios
 expo-modules-core@0.2.0 from ../node_modules/expo-modules-core/ios
 expo-splash-screen@0.11.4 from ../node_modules/expo-splash-screen/ios
 expo-structured-headers@1.1.1 from ../node_modules/expo-structured-headers/ios
 expo-updates@0.8.5 from ../node_modules/expo-updates/ios
 expo-updates-interface@0.2.2 from ../node_modules/expo-updates-interface/ios
 unimodules-app-loader@2.2.0 from ../node_modules/unimodules-app-loader/ios
 unimodules-core@7.1.1 from ../node_modules/@unimodules/core/ios
 unimodules-react-native-adapter@6.3.5 from ../node_modules/@unimodules/react-native-adapter/ios
 unimodules-task-manager-interface@6.2.0 from ../node_modules/unimodules-task-manager-interface/ios

Auto-linking React Native modules for target `sharkyamalapp`: RNGestureHandler, RNReanimated, RNScreens, and react-native-safe-area-context
Analyzing dependencies
Fetching podspec for `DoubleConversion` from `../node_modules/react-native/third-party-podspecs/DoubleConversion.podspec`
Fetching podspec for `Folly` from `../node_modules/react-native/third-party-podspecs/Folly.podspec`
Fetching podspec for `glog` from `../node_modules/react-native/third-party-podspecs/glog.podspec`
Traceback (most recent call last):
    45: from /usr/local/bin/pod:23:in `<main>'
    44: from /usr/local/bin/pod:23:in `load'
    43: from /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.6.0/gems/cocoapods-1.11.0/bin/pod:55:in `<top (required)>'
    42: from /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.6.0/gems/cocoapods-1.11.0/lib/cocoapods/command.rb:52:in `run'
    41: from /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.6.0/gems/claide-1.0.3/lib/claide/command.rb:334:in `run'
    40: from /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.6.0/gems/cocoapods-1.11.0/lib/cocoapods/command/install.rb:52:in `run'
    39: from /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.6.0/gems/cocoapods-1.11.0/lib/cocoapods/installer.rb:161:in `install!'
    38: from /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.6.0/gems/cocoapods-1.11.0/lib/cocoapods/installer.rb:240:in `resolve_dependencies'
    37: from /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.6.0/gems/cocoapods-1.11.0/lib/cocoapods/user_interface.rb:64:in `section'
    36: from /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.6.0/gems/cocoapods-1.11.0/lib/cocoapods/installer.rb:241:in `block in resolve_dependencies'
    35: from /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.6.0/gems/cocoapods-1.11.0/lib/cocoapods/installer.rb:416:in `analyze'
    34: from /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.6.0/gems/cocoapods-1.11.0/lib/cocoapods/installer/analyzer.rb:124:in `analyze'
    33: from /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.6.0/gems/cocoapods-1.11.0/lib/cocoapods/installer/analyzer.rb:1076:in `resolve_dependencies'
    32: from /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.6.0/gems/cocoapods-1.11.0/lib/cocoapods/user_interface.rb:64:in `section'
    31: from /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.6.0/gems/cocoapods-1.11.0/lib/cocoapods/installer/analyzer.rb:1077:in `block in resolve_dependencies'
    30: from /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.6.0/gems/cocoapods-1.11.0/lib/cocoapods/installer/analyzer.rb:177:in `sources'
    29: from /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.6.0/gems/cocoapods-1.11.0/lib/cocoapods/installer/analyzer.rb:177:in `map'
    28: from /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.6.0/gems/cocoapods-1.11.0/lib/cocoapods/installer/analyzer.rb:178:in `block in sources'
    27: from /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.6.0/gems/cocoapods-1.11.0/lib/cocoapods/sources_manager.rb:22:in `find_or_create_source_with_url'
    26: from /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.6.0/gems/cocoapods-core-1.11.0/lib/cocoapods-core/source/manager.rb:393:in `source_with_url'
    25: from /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.6.0/gems/cocoapods-core-1.11.0/lib/cocoapods-core/source/manager.rb:60:in `all'
    24: from /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.6.0/gems/cocoapods-core-1.11.0/lib/cocoapods-core/source/manager.rb:26:in `aggregate'
    23: from /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.6.0/gems/cocoapods-core-1.11.0/lib/cocoapods-core/source/manager.rb:331:in `aggregate_with_repos'
    22: from /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.6.0/gems/cocoapods-core-1.11.0/lib/cocoapods-core/source/manager.rb:331:in `map'
    21: from /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.6.0/gems/cocoapods-core-1.11.0/lib/cocoapods-core/source/manager.rb:331:in `block in aggregate_with_repos'
    20: from /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.6.0/gems/cocoapods-core-1.11.0/lib/cocoapods-core/source/manager.rb:322:in `source_from_path'
    19: from /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.6.0/gems/cocoapods-core-1.11.0/lib/cocoapods-core/source/manager.rb:315:in `block in source_from_path'
    18: from /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.6.0/gems/cocoapods-core-1.11.0/lib/cocoapods-core/source/manager.rb:315:in `new'
    17: from /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.6.0/gems/cocoapods-core-1.11.0/lib/cocoapods-core/cdn_source.rb:30:in `initialize'
    16: from /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.6.0/gems/cocoapods-core-1.11.0/lib/cocoapods-core/source.rb:31:in `initialize'
    15: from /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.6.0/gems/cocoapods-core-1.11.0/lib/cocoapods-core/cdn_source.rb:53:in `refresh_metadata'
    14: from /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.6.0/gems/cocoapods-core-1.11.0/lib/cocoapods-core/cdn_source.rb:338:in `download_file'
    13: from /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.6.0/gems/cocoapods-core-1.11.0/lib/cocoapods-core/cdn_source.rb:365:in `download_file_async'
    12: from /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.6.0/gems/cocoapods-core-1.11.0/lib/cocoapods-core/cdn_source.rb:372:in `download_and_save_with_retries_async'
    11: from /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.6.0/gems/cocoapods-core-1.11.0/lib/cocoapods-core/cdn_source.rb:440:in `download_typhoeus_impl_async'
    10: from /System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/2.6/usr/lib/ruby/2.6.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:54:in `require'
     9: from /System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/2.6/usr/lib/ruby/2.6.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:54:in `require'
     8: from /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.6.0/gems/typhoeus-1.4.0/lib/typhoeus.rb:2:in `<top (required)>'
     7: from /System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/2.6/usr/lib/ruby/2.6.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:54:in `require'
     6: from /System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/2.6/usr/lib/ruby/2.6.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:54:in `require'
     5: from /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.6.0/gems/ethon-0.14.0/lib/ethon.rb:3:in `<top (required)>'
     4: from /System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/2.6/usr/lib/ruby/2.6.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:54:in `require'
     3: from /System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/2.6/usr/lib/ruby/2.6.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:54:in `require'
     2: from /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.6.0/gems/ffi-1.15.4/lib/ffi.rb:3:in `<top (required)>'
     1: from /System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/2.6/usr/lib/ruby/2.6.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:54:in `require'
/System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/2.6/usr/lib/ruby/2.6.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:54:in `require': cannot load such file -- 2.6/ffi_c (LoadError)
    46: from /usr/local/bin/pod:23:in `<main>'
    45: from /usr/local/bin/pod:23:in `load'
    44: from /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.6.0/gems/cocoapods-1.11.0/bin/pod:55:in `<top (required)>'
    43: from /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.6.0/gems/cocoapods-1.11.0/lib/cocoapods/command.rb:52:in `run'
    42: from /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.6.0/gems/claide-1.0.3/lib/claide/command.rb:334:in `run'
    41: from /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.6.0/gems/cocoapods-1.11.0/lib/cocoapods/command/install.rb:52:in `run'
    40: from /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.6.0/gems/cocoapods-1.11.0/lib/cocoapods/installer.rb:161:in `install!'
    39: from /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.6.0/gems/cocoapods-1.11.0/lib/cocoapods/installer.rb:240:in `resolve_dependencies'
    38: from /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.6.0/gems/cocoapods-1.11.0/lib/cocoapods/user_interface.rb:64:in `section'
    37: from /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.6.0/gems/cocoapods-1.11.0/lib/cocoapods/installer.rb:241:in `block in resolve_dependencies'
    36: from /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.6.0/gems/cocoapods-1.11.0/lib/cocoapods/installer.rb:416:in `analyze'
    35: from /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.6.0/gems/cocoapods-1.11.0/lib/cocoapods/installer/analyzer.rb:124:in `analyze'
    34: from /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.6.0/gems/cocoapods-1.11.0/lib/cocoapods/installer/analyzer.rb:1076:in `resolve_dependencies'
    33: from /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.6.0/gems/cocoapods-1.11.0/lib/cocoapods/user_interface.rb:64:in `section'
    32: from /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.6.0/gems/cocoapods-1.11.0/lib/cocoapods/installer/analyzer.rb:1077:in `block in resolve_dependencies'
    31: from /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.6.0/gems/cocoapods-1.11.0/lib/cocoapods/installer/analyzer.rb:177:in `sources'
    30: from /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.6.0/gems/cocoapods-1.11.0/lib/cocoapods/installer/analyzer.rb:177:in `map'
    29: from /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.6.0/gems/cocoapods-1.11.0/lib/cocoapods/installer/analyzer.rb:178:in `block in sources'
    28: from /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.6.0/gems/cocoapods-1.11.0/lib/cocoapods/sources_manager.rb:22:in `find_or_create_source_with_url'
    27: from /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.6.0/gems/cocoapods-core-1.11.0/lib/cocoapods-core/source/manager.rb:393:in `source_with_url'
    26: from /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.6.0/gems/cocoapods-core-1.11.0/lib/cocoapods-core/source/manager.rb:60:in `all'
    25: from /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.6.0/gems/cocoapods-core-1.11.0/lib/cocoapods-core/source/manager.rb:26:in `aggregate'
    24: from /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.6.0/gems/cocoapods-core-1.11.0/lib/cocoapods-core/source/manager.rb:331:in `aggregate_with_repos'
    23: from /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.6.0/gems/cocoapods-core-1.11.0/lib/cocoapods-core/source/manager.rb:331:in `map'
    22: from /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.6.0/gems/cocoapods-core-1.11.0/lib/cocoapods-core/source/manager.rb:331:in `block in aggregate_with_repos'
    21: from /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.6.0/gems/cocoapods-core-1.11.0/lib/cocoapods-core/source/manager.rb:322:in `source_from_path'
    20: from /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.6.0/gems/cocoapods-core-1.11.0/lib/cocoapods-core/source/manager.rb:315:in `block in source_from_path'
    19: from /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.6.0/gems/cocoapods-core-1.11.0/lib/cocoapods-core/source/manager.rb:315:in `new'
    18: from /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.6.0/gems/cocoapods-core-1.11.0/lib/cocoapods-core/cdn_source.rb:30:in `initialize'
    17: from /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.6.0/gems/cocoapods-core-1.11.0/lib/cocoapods-core/source.rb:31:in `initialize'
    16: from /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.6.0/gems/cocoapods-core-1.11.0/lib/cocoapods-core/cdn_source.rb:53:in `refresh_metadata'
    15: from /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.6.0/gems/cocoapods-core-1.11.0/lib/cocoapods-core/cdn_source.rb:338:in `download_file'
    14: from /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.6.0/gems/cocoapods-core-1.11.0/lib/cocoapods-core/cdn_source.rb:365:in `download_file_async'
    13: from /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.6.0/gems/cocoapods-core-1.11.0/lib/cocoapods-core/cdn_source.rb:372:in `download_and_save_with_retries_async'
    12: from /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.6.0/gems/cocoapods-core-1.11.0/lib/cocoapods-core/cdn_source.rb:440:in `download_typhoeus_impl_async'
    11: from /System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/2.6/usr/lib/ruby/2.6.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:54:in `require'
    10: from /System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/2.6/usr/lib/ruby/2.6.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:54:in `require'
     9: from /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.6.0/gems/typhoeus-1.4.0/lib/typhoeus.rb:2:in `<top (required)>'
     8: from /System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/2.6/usr/lib/ruby/2.6.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:54:in `require'
     7: from /System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/2.6/usr/lib/ruby/2.6.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:54:in `require'
     6: from /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.6.0/gems/ethon-0.14.0/lib/ethon.rb:3:in `<top (required)>'
     5: from /System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/2.6/usr/lib/ruby/2.6.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:54:in `require'
     4: from /System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/2.6/usr/lib/ruby/2.6.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:54:in `require'
     3: from /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.6.0/gems/ffi-1.15.4/lib/ffi.rb:2:in `<top (required)>'
     2: from /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.6.0/gems/ffi-1.15.4/lib/ffi.rb:5:in `rescue in <top (required)>'
     1: from /System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/2.6/usr/lib/ruby/2.6.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:54:in `require'
/System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/2.6/usr/lib/ruby/2.6.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:54:in `require': dlopen(/Library/Ruby/Gems/2.6.0/gems/ffi-1.15.4/lib/ffi_c.bundle, 0x0009): missing compatible arch in /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.6.0/gems/ffi-1.15.4/lib/ffi_c.bundle - /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.6.0/gems/ffi-1.15.4/lib/ffi_c.bundle (LoadError)
    36: from /usr/local/bin/pod:23:in `<main>'
    35: from /usr/local/bin/pod:23:in `load'
    34: from /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.6.0/gems/cocoapods-1.11.0/bin/pod:55:in `<top (required)>'
    33: from /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.6.0/gems/cocoapods-1.11.0/lib/cocoapods/command.rb:52:in `run'
    32: from /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.6.0/gems/claide-1.0.3/lib/claide/command.rb:324:in `run'
    31: from /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.6.0/gems/claide-1.0.3/lib/claide/command.rb:337:in `rescue in run'
    30: from /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.6.0/gems/claide-1.0.3/lib/claide/command.rb:396:in `handle_exception'
    29: from /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.6.0/gems/cocoapods-1.11.0/lib/cocoapods/command.rb:66:in `report_error'
    28: from /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.6.0/gems/cocoapods-1.11.0/lib/cocoapods/user_interface/error_report.rb:24:in `report'
    27: from /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.6.0/gems/cocoapods-1.11.0/lib/cocoapods/user_interface/error_report.rb:77:in `stack'
    26: from /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.6.0/gems/cocoapods-1.11.0/lib/cocoapods/user_interface/error_report.rb:173:in `repo_information'
    25: from /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.6.0/gems/cocoapods-core-1.11.0/lib/cocoapods-core/source/manager.rb:60:in `all'
    24: from /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.6.0/gems/cocoapods-core-1.11.0/lib/cocoapods-core/source/manager.rb:26:in `aggregate'
    23: from /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.6.0/gems/cocoapods-core-1.11.0/lib/cocoapods-core/source/manager.rb:331:in `aggregate_with_repos'
    22: from /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.6.0/gems/cocoapods-core-1.11.0/lib/cocoapods-core/source/manager.rb:331:in `map'
    21: from /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.6.0/gems/cocoapods-core-1.11.0/lib/cocoapods-core/source/manager.rb:331:in `block in aggregate_with_repos'
    20: from /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.6.0/gems/cocoapods-core-1.11.0/lib/cocoapods-core/source/manager.rb:322:in `source_from_path'
    19: from /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.6.0/gems/cocoapods-core-1.11.0/lib/cocoapods-core/source/manager.rb:315:in `block in source_from_path'
    18: from /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.6.0/gems/cocoapods-core-1.11.0/lib/cocoapods-core/source/manager.rb:315:in `new'
    17: from /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.6.0/gems/cocoapods-core-1.11.0/lib/cocoapods-core/cdn_source.rb:30:in `initialize'
    16: from /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.6.0/gems/cocoapods-core-1.11.0/lib/cocoapods-core/source.rb:31:in `initialize'
    15: from /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.6.0/gems/cocoapods-core-1.11.0/lib/cocoapods-core/cdn_source.rb:53:in `refresh_metadata'
    14: from /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.6.0/gems/cocoapods-core-1.11.0/lib/cocoapods-core/cdn_source.rb:338:in `download_file'
    13: from /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.6.0/gems/cocoapods-core-1.11.0/lib/cocoapods-core/cdn_source.rb:365:in `download_file_async'
    12: from /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.6.0/gems/cocoapods-core-1.11.0/lib/cocoapods-core/cdn_source.rb:372:in `download_and_save_with_retries_async'
    11: from /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.6.0/gems/cocoapods-core-1.11.0/lib/cocoapods-core/cdn_source.rb:440:in `download_typhoeus_impl_async'
    10: from /System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/2.6/usr/lib/ruby/2.6.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:54:in `require'
     9: from /System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/2.6/usr/lib/ruby/2.6.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:54:in `require'
     8: from /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.6.0/gems/typhoeus-1.4.0/lib/typhoeus.rb:2:in `<top (required)>'
     7: from /System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/2.6/usr/lib/ruby/2.6.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:54:in `require'
     6: from /System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/2.6/usr/lib/ruby/2.6.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:54:in `require'
     5: from /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.6.0/gems/ethon-0.14.0/lib/ethon.rb:3:in `<top (required)>'
     4: from /System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/2.6/usr/lib/ruby/2.6.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:54:in `require'
     3: from /System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/2.6/usr/lib/ruby/2.6.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:54:in `require'
     2: from /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.6.0/gems/ffi-1.15.4/lib/ffi.rb:3:in `<top (required)>'
     1: from /System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/2.6/usr/lib/ruby/2.6.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:54:in `require'
/System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/2.6/usr/lib/ruby/2.6.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:54:in `require': cannot load such file -- 2.6/ffi_c (LoadError)
    37: from /usr/local/bin/pod:23:in `<main>'
    36: from /usr/local/bin/pod:23:in `load'
    35: from /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.6.0/gems/cocoapods-1.11.0/bin/pod:55:in `<top (required)>'
    34: from /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.6.0/gems/cocoapods-1.11.0/lib/cocoapods/command.rb:52:in `run'
    33: from /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.6.0/gems/claide-1.0.3/lib/claide/command.rb:324:in `run'
    32: from /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.6.0/gems/claide-1.0.3/lib/claide/command.rb:337:in `rescue in run'
    31: from /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.6.0/gems/claide-1.0.3/lib/claide/command.rb:396:in `handle_exception'
    30: from /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.6.0/gems/cocoapods-1.11.0/lib/cocoapods/command.rb:66:in `report_error'
    29: from /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.6.0/gems/cocoapods-1.11.0/lib/cocoapods/user_interface/error_report.rb:24:in `report'
    28: from /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.6.0/gems/cocoapods-1.11.0/lib/cocoapods/user_interface/error_report.rb:77:in `stack'
    27: from /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.6.0/gems/cocoapods-1.11.0/lib/cocoapods/user_interface/error_report.rb:173:in `repo_information'
    26: from /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.6.0/gems/cocoapods-core-1.11.0/lib/cocoapods-core/source/manager.rb:60:in `all'
    25: from /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.6.0/gems/cocoapods-core-1.11.0/lib/cocoapods-core/source/manager.rb:26:in `aggregate'
    24: from /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.6.0/gems/cocoapods-core-1.11.0/lib/cocoapods-core/source/manager.rb:331:in `aggregate_with_repos'
    23: from /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.6.0/gems/cocoapods-core-1.11.0/lib/cocoapods-core/source/manager.rb:331:in `map'
    22: from /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.6.0/gems/cocoapods-core-1.11.0/lib/cocoapods-core/source/manager.rb:331:in `block in aggregate_with_repos'
    21: from /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.6.0/gems/cocoapods-core-1.11.0/lib/cocoapods-core/source/manager.rb:322:in `source_from_path'
    20: from /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.6.0/gems/cocoapods-core-1.11.0/lib/cocoapods-core/source/manager.rb:315:in `block in source_from_path'
    19: from /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.6.0/gems/cocoapods-core-1.11.0/lib/cocoapods-core/source/manager.rb:315:in `new'
    18: from /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.6.0/gems/cocoapods-core-1.11.0/lib/cocoapods-core/cdn_source.rb:30:in `initialize'
    17: from /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.6.0/gems/cocoapods-core-1.11.0/lib/cocoapods-core/source.rb:31:in `initialize'
    16: from /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.6.0/gems/cocoapods-core-1.11.0/lib/cocoapods-core/cdn_source.rb:53:in `refresh_metadata'
    15: from /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.6.0/gems/cocoapods-core-1.11.0/lib/cocoapods-core/cdn_source.rb:338:in `download_file'
    14: from /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.6.0/gems/cocoapods-core-1.11.0/lib/cocoapods-core/cdn_source.rb:365:in `download_file_async'
    13: from /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.6.0/gems/cocoapods-core-1.11.0/lib/cocoapods-core/cdn_source.rb:372:in `download_and_save_with_retries_async'
    12: from /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.6.0/gems/cocoapods-core-1.11.0/lib/cocoapods-core/cdn_source.rb:440:in `download_typhoeus_impl_async'
    11: from /System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/2.6/usr/lib/ruby/2.6.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:54:in `require'
    10: from /System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/2.6/usr/lib/ruby/2.6.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:54:in `require'
     9: from /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.6.0/gems/typhoeus-1.4.0/lib/typhoeus.rb:2:in `<top (required)>'
     8: from /System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/2.6/usr/lib/ruby/2.6.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:54:in `require'
     7: from /System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/2.6/usr/lib/ruby/2.6.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:54:in `require'
     6: from /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.6.0/gems/ethon-0.14.0/lib/ethon.rb:3:in `<top (required)>'
     5: from /System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/2.6/usr/lib/ruby/2.6.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:54:in `require'
     4: from /System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/2.6/usr/lib/ruby/2.6.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:54:in `require'
     3: from /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.6.0/gems/ffi-1.15.4/lib/ffi.rb:2:in `<top (required)>'
     2: from /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.6.0/gems/ffi-1.15.4/lib/ffi.rb:5:in `rescue in <top (required)>'
     1: from /System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/2.6/usr/lib/ruby/2.6.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:54:in `require'
/System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/2.6/usr/lib/ruby/2.6.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:54:in `require': dlopen(/Library/Ruby/Gems/2.6.0/gems/ffi-1.15.4/lib/ffi_c.bundle, 0x0009): missing compatible arch in /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.6.0/gems/ffi-1.15.4/lib/ffi_c.bundle - /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.6.0/gems/ffi-1.15.4/lib/ffi_c.bundle (LoadError)
```

This is my package.json:

```
{
  "main": "index.js",
  "scripts": {
    "android": "react-native run-android",
    "ios": "react-native run-ios",
    "web": "expo start --web",
    "start": "react-native start",
    "postinstall": "rm -rf node_modules/expo/node_modules/react-native-safe-area-context"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "@react-navigation/native": "^6.0.2",
    "@react-navigation/native-stack": "^6.1.0",
    "axios": "^0.21.3",
    "expo": "~42.0.1",
    "expo-splash-screen": "~0.11.2",
    "expo-status-bar": "~1.0.4",
    "expo-updates": "~0.8.1",
    "react": "16.13.1",
    "react-dom": "16.13.1",
    "react-native": "~0.63.4",
    "react-native-gesture-handler": "~1.10.2",
    "react-native-loading-view": "^1.0.1",
    "react-native-reanimated": "~2.2.0",
    "react-native-safe-area-context": "3.2.0",
    "react-native-screens": "^3.4.0",
    "react-native-unimodules": "~0.14.5",
    "react-native-web": "~0.13.12"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@babel/core": "^7.9.0"
  },
  "private": true
}
```

How can I fix it?

Comment: Why do you run "postinstall" in the ios folder? Do you want to run "pod install"?

Comment: post install. I did not run postinstall.